# How can I prevent bad inputs when storing phone numbers as strings?

Tags: java, string, validation, integer, vcf-vcard

I am creating a phonebook program that can read VCards. The problem is with phone numbers. Normally, they will be like this in the United States:

`0771234560`

But if the phone number is from a foreign country, it would look like this.

`+94771234560` or maybe `(22)772324000`

Now there are `+` and `()` signs to deal with! I am currently converting phone numbers (VCards contain them as Strings) to numbers. However, if I take allow phone numbers as strings, then a user could do something crazy, like insert a name as a phone number in the contact form.

How can I store phone numbers as strings but prevent problematic entries?

Comment: I would strip out all non-digit characters.  Those are display issues.

Comment: I would use a string and use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196771/format-a-string-using-regex-in-java to make it in the correct regex

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Definitely use a string, but validate it. Just because it's a string doesn't mean you have to accept *any* data. You should consider using a regular expression (or perhaps a series of regular expressions) to validate the data.

Don't just limit it to specific characters - for example, you don't want to accept ")0(" as a phone number - use sensible patterns. The [Wikipedia page on local conventions for phone numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers) may prove helpful on this front - or you could look for other sources. You may also want to *consider* being somewhat lenient, as not everyone will follow exact patterns. There's a delicate balance to be achieved though.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a numeric type for phone numbers, stick with a `String`.

Do some form of input validation. Define some restrictions on your phone numbers, and when reading the card, check the `String` against your format: if the phone number doesn't match your restrictions, then reject it.

Search around this site for questions/answers regarding phone number validation.

Answer (score 4):

What would adding two phone numbers mean? So, IMO, not a number.

You should still attempt to validate, but if you want to accept any and all arbitrary international numbers, including local conventions for how they're written, that'll be frustrating.