# Vectorized format function for Pandas series

Tags: python, string, formatting, pandas

Say I start with a `Series` of unformatted phone numbers (as strings), and I would like to format them as (XXX) YYY-ZZZZ.

I can get the sub-components of my input using regular expressions and `str.match` or `str.extract`.  And I can perform the formatting using the result of either:

```
ser = pd.Series(data=['1234567890', '2345678901', '3456789012']) 

matched = ser.str.match(r'(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})')

extracted = ser.astype(str).str.extract(r'(?P<first>\d{3})(?P<second>\d{3})(?P<third>\d{4})')

formatmatched = matched.apply(lambda x: '({0}) {1}-{2}'.format(*x))
print 'formatmatched'
print formatmatched

formatextracted = extracted.apply(lambda x: '({first}) {second}-{third}'.format(**x.to_dict()), axis=1)
print 'formatextracted'
print formatextracted
```

Results:

```
formatmatched
0    (123) 456-7890
1    (234) 567-8901
2    (345) 678-9012
dtype: object
formatextracted
0    (123) 456-7890
1    (234) 567-8901
2    (345) 678-9012
dtype: object
```

Is there a vectorized way to apply that formatting command in either context?

Comment: possible duplicate of [format phone number in csv using pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074919/format-phone-number-in-csv-using-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this directly with `Series.str.replace()`:

```
In [47]: s = pandas.Series(["1234567890", "5552348866", "13434"])

In [49]: s
Out[49]: 
0    1234567890
1    5552348866
2         13434
dtype: object

In [50]: s.str.replace(r"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", r"(\1) \2-\3")
Out[50]: 
0    (123) 456-7890
1    (555) 234-8866
2             13434
dtype: object
```

You could also imagine doing another transformation first to remove any non-digit characters.

Comment: wait, I came up with something before @AndyHayden did?! ;)

Comment: This is the solution I knew was out there somewhere.  Still need to get my head around all the possibilities with `replace`.  More generally, can `str.replace` handle named groups?

Comment: @DJ_8one6 yep, syntax is same as re.sub: `s.str.replace('^(?P<a>\d{3})(?P<b>\d{3})(?P<c>\d{4})$', r'\g<a> \g<b>-\g<c>')`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
import pandas as pd
ser = pd.Series(data=['1234567890', '2345678901', '3456789012']) 
def f(val):
    return '({0}) {1}-{2}'.format(val[:3],val[3:6],val[6:])
print ser.apply(f)
```

Comment: Was trying to handle the more general problems that regexes are best able to handle.

Comment: OK, but the idea is the same, just use the regex approach inside the function. Hope it helps :)